# Convert Bson to Json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, bson

Crome developer tool show this

```
console.log('DATA*** ', data[0]._id);
```

**error :** `DATA***  Object {_bsontype: "ObjectID", id: "YIä↵P¨H0"}`

How I can convert it into normal JSON object?

Comment: Have you looked into [bsondump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/bsondump/)?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is 
*JSON.stringify()*

JSON.stringify(objectToSerialize)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JSON.stringify() and then JSON.parse() to convert bson to valid json.

```
const dataString = JSON.stringify(data[0]);
const parsed = JSON.parse(dataString);

console.log(parsed._id);
```

Other bson types may give you its associated representation in [Canonical format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). For example, if you used the **decimal** bsonType in your mongodb it will present it like so:

```
...(continuing from code block above)

console.log(parsed.aDecimalNumber); // { $numberDecimal: 1.00 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to call the .tostring() function on the id field.

The objectId is held as a special type stored in hex to reduce size.  You'll need to use the toString function to convert it to the 24 ascii char string

https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/1.0-branch/lib/bson/objectid.js#L171-L179

```
console.log('DATA*** ', data[0]._id.toString());
```